# productsign is not able to find cert from keychain

Tags: macos, code-signing-certificate, productsign

We are trying to sign a Mac installer (.pkg file) using the following command.

```
productsign --sign "Developer ID Installer: MyCompany, Inc." unsigned_installer.pkg signed_package.pkg
```

But we are getting the following error.

```
productsign: error: Could not find appropriate signing identity for “Developer ID Installer: MyCompany, Inc.”.
```

When we try to find the certificates using `security -v find-identity -p codesigning`, we get the following output.

```
Policy: Code Signing
Matching identities
1) 1234....6789 "MyCompany, Inc."
   1 identities found

Valid identities only
1) 1234....6789 "MyCompany, Inc."
   1 valid identities found
```

Can you give us any on how to troubleshoot and fix this issue?

Comment: Maybe try using the number instead ... `"Developer ID Installer: 1234...6789"`

Comment: Tried that as well. We are getting the same error.

Comment: What does the item in parentheses read next to it? (eg. `1234...6789 "Name" (THIS)`)

Comment: There are no parenthesis in the output of `security` command. All it says is `1234...6789 "Name"`.

Comment: You might need to request your signing identities from the member center or refresh your provisioning profiles: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/MaintainingCertificates/MaintainingCertificates.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012582-CH31-SW6

Comment: Thanks for this info. So does this mean that we need to get the certificate from Apple only? And that we can't sign the installer with a certificate provided by some 3rd party like DigiCert?

Comment: You're welcome! You can buy codesigning certs from DigiCert, although I'm not sure they handle everything the Apple certs do. Also the Apple certa are included with the membership to the developer program, and are less expensive — so I'd recommend going that route.

Comment: Thanks! Looks like that's the only way!